# Is this an expected behavior? Encrypted Text visibility

Tags: apex, encryption

I would like to know how it works the encrypted text visibility in apex code. In some classes I'm able to see the unmasked text field but in others I see 'XXXXXXXX' when I use `System.debug`.

I'm using the same User profile.  As you see in the image with the same code I get different results.

[image: Anonymous Window result]

Comment: Nice question! Set up a username and stay a while. :)

Answer (score 7):

It is expected that **you should be able to see it**. From [Classic Encryption for Custom Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm):

> - Encrypted field data is not always masked in the debug log. Encrypted field data is masked if the Apex request originates from an Apex Web service, a trigger, a workflow, an inline Visualforce page (a page embedded in a page layout), or a Visualforce email template. In other cases, encrypted field data isn’t masked in the debug log, like for example when running Apex from the Developer Console.

I thought all `Apex` had access, but I'll have to dig more to see why it is *not* shown in your first approach. It seems like a bug for it to be masked at all, since `Execute Anonymous` seems explicitly whitelisted:

> encrypted field data isn’t masked in the debug log...when running Apex from the Developer Console

Despite the fact it seems like a bug, there are [no Known Issues for Classic Encryption](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?keywords=classic%20encryption).